# UIImage not saving to Camera Roll

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, camera, core-image

I'm currently writing a photo app for iOS in Swift. I'm using the CoreImage Framework to generate a pixel effect on a `UIImageView` selected by the user. However, I'm having trouble saving the "pixeled" image to the iPhone's Camera Roll. Normally I use

`UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(pixeledImage,nil,nil,nil)`

but it's not saving the `UIImage`. I have given the app full access to the photo library on the device. It will be helpful if someone could help me figure this out. My image picker:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    var imagetobepassed: UIImage!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func Cameratapped(sender: AnyObject) {

        var camera = UIImagePickerController()
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            camera.delegate = self
            camera.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
            camera.allowsEditing = false
            self.presentViewController(camera, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func photolib(sender: AnyObject) {
        var photo = UIImagePickerController()
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            photo.delegate = self
            photo.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
            photo.allowsEditing = false
            self.presentViewController(photo, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
        imagetobepassed = image
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func editorPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "image" {
            var editorview = segue.destinationViewController as! EditorViewController
            editorview.imagerecived = imagetobepassed
        }
    }
}
```

And my editor:

```
import UIKit

class EditorViewController: UIViewController {

    var imagerecived:UIImage!
    var pixeledImage:UIImage!
    var savedImage:UIImage!

    @IBOutlet var imageview: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        pixel()
    }

    // this function will prduce the pixel effect
    func pixel() {
        var regularImage = CIImage(image: imagerecived)
        var filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPixellate")
        filter.setDefaults()
        filter.setValue(regularImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        var output = filter.outputImage
        pixeledImage = UIImage(CIImage: output)
        imageview.image = pixeledImage
    }

    @IBAction func SaveTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        println(pixeledImage)
         UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(pixeledImage,nil,nil,nil) // not saving image
    }
```

How can I make this work? I do see this error:

> 2015-05-16 23:40:05.416 Pixelate2[21579:3341726] Connection to assetsd
>   was interrupted or assetsd died

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: @Vizllx  2015-05-16 23:40:05.416 Pixelate2[21579:3341726] Connection to assetsd was interrupted or assetsd died

Comment: This means you are getting a memory warning!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue using this code:

```
@IBAction func SaveTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    let softwareContext = CIContext(options: [kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer:true])
    let cgimg = softwareContext.createCGImage(savedImage, 
                                              fromRect: savedImage.extent())

    let libary = ALAssetsLibrary()
    libary.writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum(cgimg, metadata: savedImage.properties(), 
                                        completionBlock: nil)
}
```

Comment: I actually solved a similar problem the same way. After using CoreImage to create a UIImage, I had a UIImage which may not have been fully baked. For example, its `cgImage` property was nil. I created an intermediate image using `createCGImage()` and it then worked.

Answer (score 1):

First use this line to save image:-

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(pixeledImage, self, "image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:", nil)
```

Now implement this method,to catch the error you are getting:-

```
func image(image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo:UnsafePointer<Void>) {
    if error == nil {

      }
    else
      {
      //log the error out here ,if any  
      }
}
```

There is another work around, if you are getting memory warning !

```
ALAssetsLibrary* lib = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[lib writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:imageData metadata:nil
                      completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error)
{
    // do whatever in the completion handler 
}];
```

Comment: I tried both of your answers, and I'm still getting the same results. Do you have anymore ideas